# Displaying a UserProfile field in Django Admin outside listing

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have `phone` field in my `UserProfile`. How can I have it displayed in `Django Admin › Auth › Users` listing from the outside (list display) - not the inside of the record?

I now have:

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'userprofile__phone')
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)


# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

userprofile__phone is not recognized.

Comment: what do you mean by from the outside ? You mean in the list display ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it would be

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone')
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)

    def phone(self, obj):
        try:
            phone = obj.userprofile.phone #Or change this to how you would access the userprofile object - This was assuming that the User, Profile relationship is OneToOne
            return phone
        except:
            return ""

    phone.short_description = 'Phone'

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

More details on [`list_display` here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)